# ¿Cómo cambiar permisos de escritura aplicación web?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Actualmente tengo una aplicación en `Tomcat` donde el usuario puede subir imágenes, estas imágenes se guardan en una ruta del servidor `/home/linux_user/fact`.

El detalle es cuando sube los archivos: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Guarda las imágenes con `permisos 644`.

¿Hay alguna manera de que al subir las imágenes por la aplicación, se guarde con permisos diferentes?

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

> **Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#archivo').ajaxfileupload({
                'action': 'FileUploadIncidencia?nombre_archivo=<%=id_fact%>',
                'timeout': '50000',
                'onComplete': function(response) {
                    $('#upload_pdf').hide();
                    $('#message_archivo').show();
                    var statusVal = JSON.stringify(response.status);
                    if (statusVal == "false") {
                        $("#message_archivo").html("<font color='red'>Extension del archivo incorrecta.</font>");
                    } else {

                        $("#message_archivo").html("<font color='green'>Imagen agregado correctamente.</font>");
                    }
                },
                'onStart': function() {
                    $('#upload').show();
                    $('#message_archivo').hide();
                }
    });
```

> **Servlet**

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String nombre_archivo = request.getParameter("nombre_archivo");

    String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/home/linux_user/fact";

    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                    new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                String name = "";
                if (!item.isFormField()) {

                    name = name + ".png";

                    item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                    //System.out.println(name);
                }
            }


            request.setAttribute("message", "Archivo Subido");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ex.getStackTrace();
            ex.getMessage();
        }

    } else {
        request.setAttribute("message",
                "Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya verificaste que el permisos tiene la ruta /home/linux_user/fact ?

Comment: Sí, de hecho le di permisos 777 a la carpeta fact, pero aún así me sigue poniendo los mismos permisos 644.

Comment: ¿Qué permisos quieres que tenga?¿Más o menos? Y ¿para qué?

Comment: Intenta esto a ver si funciona tal como quieres... No lo probe. `File file = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name);
                      file.setReadable(true, false);
                      file.setExecutable(true, false);
                      file.setWritable(true, false);  item.write(file);`

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo.